# Suggestions to improve Google Sheets performance on laptop

Tags: ssd

I have a Dell Inspiron 15.6 inch AMD 3541 (Processor: AMD E1-6010 APU) and have already upgraded the 2GB RAM to 8GB.

The RAM upgrade gave almost no visible performance increase. Upgrading to Windows 10 neither. Essentially I only have to use the laptop for Google Sheets and we have some fairly complex sheets.

The sheets perform absolutely fine on newer machines but are so slow to load and edit cells using any browser.

Would and upgrade to an SSD likely impact the performance specifically in chrome / google docs?? I don't awfully want to keep spending more money on a dud!

Am using Chrome browser (although tried Firefox and Edge) and have tested Performance ModePower Settings>>Performance Mode..

Comment: Maybe not... Perhaps you could try putting your computer into performance mode in the power settings?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: This CPU is a dud and you should not waste more money on this laptop. A better choice might be to take the RAM and Windows license over to a new machine, then run a lightweight linux off this one to make the most of its poor CPU performance.

Comment: Thanks - was considering running Ubuntu or similar on it although wasnt sure how Chromium (or any linux browser) handles google sheets.